# Is there a module that handles meta tags?

Tags: drupal-6, meta-tags

Which, if any, Drupal 6 modules handle meta tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 modules that handle meta tags: [Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) and [Integrated Metatags](http://drupal.org/project/int_meta).

They are two different modules with different purposes. While the first one allows any user to set the meta tags for nodes or user profiles, the second one allows the administrator users to change the meta tags (it uses a custom permission).

If then you ask which module is better, I can report that the first is currently not developed; in fact the actual maintainer is looking for a new maintainer. The second module is still maintained, and the last update has been done on January of this year.
Both the modules don't have a version for Drupal 7. If you are planning to pass to Drupal 7 (which should have a first official release in the next months — where by official release I mean a release that is not a beta, nor a release candidate version), then I would wait to adopt one of those modules to see if they will be ported to Drupal 7.

#### Update

The Integrated Metatags module is now marked as *not supported*, it doesn't have any new releases since September 30, 2013; plus, there is just a version for Drupal 6.
The Nodewords module doesn't have any Drupal 7 version, but the [Metatag](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module is supposed to be used for Drupal 7; it also has a module to import data from the Nodewords module.

At the moment, the Nodewords module is still the one I would use.